# VB.NET Remove Item in ComboBox after placing in Listview

Tags: vb.net

I want to remove item from Combobox after using it in Listview

I fill combobox in Form_load with:

```
With CmbCode
.items.clear
For N 1 to 9999
.items.add(N)
Next
End With
```

Here I need Something to remove the Used numbers From Combobox (CmbCode)
I use a library Class
To fill the listview:

```
Dim Formatter As New BinaryFormatter
Dim AL As New ArrayList
ReadFile.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)
AL=CType(Formatter.Deserialize(ReadFile), ArrayList)
Dim itm As Object
For Each itm In AL
Lsv1.Itmes.Add(itm)
Next
ReadFile.Close
Formatter = Nothing
```

I have no idea how to remove the used numbers (In Listview) from the combobox.
Any Idea how to approach the problem.

Comment: Every time you transfer a number `n` from the combobx to the listview, also do this: `ComboBox1.Items.Remove(n)`.

Comment: @laancelot Agreed, but when Load_form event runs the combobox is filled again from 1 to 9999. This is my problem to remove the used in Load_form Event

Answer (score 1):

Don't use that loop when loading.  Call `Items.AddRange` to add all the items in one go.  If you keep the items that you have previously removed in a list then you can easily exclude those when loading, e.g.

```
Dim items = Enumerable.Range(1, 9999).Except(previouslyRemovedItems).ToArray()

CmbCode.Items.AddRange(items)
```

I haven't tested that and it might be that `AddRange` will not accept a value-type array, so you may need to cast as type `Object`, i.e.

```
Dim items = Enumerable.Range(1, 9999).Except(previouslyRemovedItems).Cast(Of Object)().ToArray()
```